# Full Calendar agenda view with many all-day events

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in a new web app and have ran into a problem once we deployed.  On the Agenda view with the all-day slot enabled the all-day slot expands as events are added.  this did not present any issues during our initial test but we have ran into a problem with many events.  The all-day slot continues to expand eventually making the agenda view disappear or be too small to be functional.  Is there a work around to add a scroll bar to the all-day tab or set a min height for the agenda view?  I have tried everything I can think of and have been unable to get anything to work.  Please see attached screen shot from the calendar test files.

[image: Calendar Agenda Issue]

Answer (score 0):

While you can restrict the size of the all day section my modifiying it's class. The events themselves are positioned by absolute x - y coordinates on the page and aren't actually inside the all day section at all, so scrolling that box would be pointless anyway.

I'd say without modifying the source considerably this is not possible.

I'm not sure what you mean by setting a min-height?